# Change functionality of Microsoft officejs

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I have developed an Excel add-in project. I want to change some actions in my Excel add-in. I would like to restrict users from being able to resize the add-in task pane. I would like to remove the personality menu from my add-in. It is possible to do both. If there is any documentation for that?.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible in web add-ins. `OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for that.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .